# Laravel chain With clause with multiple conditions

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Notifications table that has the following content:

```
id  | user_id   | type      | table_id
1   | 1         | Receipt   | 201
2   | 1         | Receipt   | 391
3   | 2         | Reminder  | null
4   | 2         | Ticket    | 30
```

The column `type` can hold different values such as Receipt, Reminder or Ticket and the `table_id` column refers to the corresponding Table ID of the type selected. `table_id` can be null sometimes.

I'd like to know if there's a possibility to retrieve the data of `Notifications` table with all the chains already applied, like such:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        user_id: 1,
        type: Receipt,
        table_id: 201,
        receipt: { .... }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        user_id: 1,
        type: Receipt,
        table_id: 201, 
        receipt: { .... }
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        user_id: 2,
        type: Reminder,
        table_id: null
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        user_id: 2,
        type: Ticket,
        table_id: 30,
        ticket: { .... }
    },      
]
```

I have the following Model:

```
class Notifications extends Model
{
    public function receipt()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\Receipts', 'id', 'table_id');
    }
    
    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\Tickets', 'id', 'table_id');
    }
    
    public function scopeWithReceipt($query)
    {
        return $query->with('receipt')->where('type', 'Receipt');
    }
    
    public function scopeWithTicket($query)
    {
        return $query->with('ticket')->where('type', 'Ticket');
    }
}
```

If I do something like:

```
\App\Models\Notifications::withReceipt()->get();
```

It returns only the rows with `type = Receipt`. If I add more "with chains" it doesn't return anything:

```
\App\Models\Notifications::withReceipt()->withTicket()->get();
```

Is it possible to accomplish what I want without looping the rows? I know I can do something like:

```
$notifications = \App\Models\Notifications::all();

foreach ($notifications as $notification)
{
    switch ($notification->type)
    {
        case 'Receipt':
            $notification->receipt = ..
            break;
        case 'Reminder':
            break;
        case 'Ticket':
            $notification->ticket = ..
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to use orWhere https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#or-where-clauses and see the section on logical grouping https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#logical-grouping

Comment: Can any of your models Receipt/Ticket/Reminder belong to more than 1 Notification? Can your Notification model have more than 1 relationship?

Comment: @Luciano no, only 1-to-1.